# Lightweight, general-purpose, stable, standalone/embedded SQL server for Windows?

Tags: c#, sql, database, rdbms

I realise this question is a little subjective, but I think there are only a very small number of DBMSs that match the requirement.

I'm looking for some recommendations for a standalone SQL server. Something that can either be bundled on compile, or already have a driver built-in to Windows.

I'd usually use MySQL or MS SQL, depending on environment, but I'd like to "graduate" to SQL for things I'd usually do in XML files for Windows.

The db should be accessible without an internet connection, and preferably be stable and mature. I don't mind what flavour SQL it is. It'd only really be for a single concurrent user at a time, i.e. to store program user data.

I'm looking for something "general-purpose", that I can rapidly integrate with new projects/small tools I make.

From my research, the two I'm coming up with, that still look like they're in development are: the well known [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), and also [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/). What are the pro's and con's of each?

Have I missed any killer standalone SQL servers? I've used Sybase SQL Anywhere in the past, but it has its quirks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx)? Sounds like it might meet your criteria.

Comment: I hadn't considered SQL Compact, didn't know it existed to be honest. Thanks.

Comment: I don't suppose you're able to provide some short info on how to implement CE? I've tried `Solution Explorer > Right-click Project > Add > New item > Data > Local Database`, but I'm not sure exactly what to do from there. Thanks!

Comment: @DannyBeckett: I don't have much experience with it. It was in a project I inherited a while back. Seemed to work okay, but I wasn't the one to configure it.

Comment: For reference, to get started adding a new CE db to a project in VS: Project > Add New Item > Local Database > Type a name, e.g. MyDB > Add > The *Data Source Configuration Wizard* opens with the new `MyDB.sdf` file chosen as the data connection > Next > Next > Finish on the *Choose Your Database Objects* page (no database objects are available because this is a new database). `MyDB.sdf` and `MyDBDataSet.xsd` are added to the project.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is one of the most killer at this kind. Many standalone programs uses it. And it works well on .NET

Comment: Would you say it's easier to implement and create the db, in SQLite, than with SQL CE?

Comment: If you use Visual Studio, it's easier in SQL CE, ofcourse. But SQLite have program to work with tables, that not quite more difficult. You can start with SQL CE. But it's very limited db. About Firebird, it has stored procedures. If you don't need this feature, SQLite still the best choice

Comment: Do you have a preferred GUI for making SQLite db's for C# progs with?

Comment: Thanks for your help Aibar! I'll investigate SQLite shortly, and may well change my accepted answer.